# I'm not able to connect to wifi on Debian 10

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, broadcom

I've installed Debian 10.5 few days ago, after playing with drives and packages I was able to set up required broadcom drivers and was able to connect to wifi.

Because I've accomplished my mission I was quite happy thus I went sleep that day. Tho in the morning I saw that wifi connection is not there any more. It shown up as valid and I can see all wifi connections around, but no luck in connection to any. It keep saying that "Authentication Required by Wifi network".

**$sudo lspci | grep controller**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 6000 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:15.0 DMA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO DMA Controller (rev 03)
00:15.4 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO GSPI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Limited 720p FaceTime HD Camera
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
```

**$sudo iwconfig**

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          enx1c4bd6b517a2  no wireless extensions
```

**$  sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[connection]
wifi.cloned-mac-address=random
[connection]
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=random
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

If any additional information required, I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Need help) bump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that somehow issue was behind mac dual-boot system.
My build was like this: MAC OS on main SSD and Debian 10 on external SSD.
From time to time I was booting between MAC OS and DEB, and it affects the network card on Debian site.
Not sure how to fix it, so I uninstalled MAC OS from main SSD and install Deb there as well. As for now I have no issues with networking (i've reinstalled all drivers, with no MAC OS on main SSD that solve an issue for me)